# How to refresh devexpress listbox without refreshing the page in ASP.NET using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I'm working on a form where I have to have an upload control and a listbox to show the uploaded files. Right now the only way to show the change is to refresh the whole page. My boss wants the upload to automatically show in the listbox. I have been unable to find anything to do this after days of searching.

[image]

VB code:

```
Protected Sub BootstrapUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Web.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs) Handles BootstrapUploadControl1.FileUploadComplete
    Dim fileName = e.UploadedFile.FileName
    Dim contentType = e.UploadedFile.ContentType
    Try
        Using fs As Stream = e.UploadedFile.FileContent
            Using br As New BinaryReader(fs)
                Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CType(fs.Length, Integer))
                Dim constr As String = "Data Source=mgm-sql-pub101;Initial Catalog=KidVid;Integrated Security=True;"
                Dim query = "INSERT INTO Attachments(RequestID,FileName,FileBytes,Description) VALUES (@RequestID, @FileName, @FileBytes, @Description)"
                Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constr)
                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RequestID", 1)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FileName", fileName)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FileBytes", bytes)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", "Binary File")
                    Try
                        con.Open()
                        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                            MsgBox("It's open! Yay!")
                        End If
                        Dim obj As Object = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        MsgBox("Record inserted successfully. ID = " & obj.ToString())
                        con.Close()
                        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                            MsgBox("It's closed! Yay!")
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Throw ex
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

HTML:

```
                        <div class="col">
                            <h5><i class='fas fa-paperclip' style='font-size:24px'></i>Attachments:</h5>
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-5">
                                    <dx:BootstrapUploadControl ID="BootstrapUploadControl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" UploadMode="Auto" ShowProgressPanel="True" ShowUploadButton="True"></dx:BootstrapUploadControl>
                                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="ASPxButton" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <h6><i class="fas fa-file-download" style="font-size: 24px"></i> Double-click filename to download file:</h6>
                            <dx:BootstrapListBox ID="AttachmentsListBox" runat="server" DataSourceID="KidVidAttachmentsDataSource" AutoPostBack="true">
                                <Fields>
                                    <dx:BootstrapListBoxField FieldName="FileName"></dx:BootstrapListBoxField>
                                </Fields>
                            </dx:BootstrapListBox>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="KidVidAttachmentsDataSource" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KidVidConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [FileName] FROM [Attachments] ORDER BY [FileName]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Well, does the upload control you are using have any client side events that trigger? the simple answer is if yes, then after the up-load simple allow a post-back (page refresh) and the file list in that box will then be updated. I don't think the post-back is a issue, the issue is HAVING a post back occur after say the user selected 5 files, and they are ALL done up-loading. At that point, a refresh is appropriate and desired. The only question is does the up-loader in question have a "all files up-loaded event" that triggers in client side code (if yes, then post-back at that point).

Comment: We are trying to do it without postback. The user uploads a file by hitting the upload button. They want it to simply appear in the listbox without the postback. I've seen comboboxes do this, but I can't figure it out for a listbox.

Comment: Well, the solution that presents a solution here kind of solves the answer! If your up-load control does not have a nice client event that fires when the 4 files selected for up-load don't exist, then it going to be difficult.  On the other hand, if the up-load control DOES have a client side event then you can do this.  In other words, you CAN do a ajax call to a web method after the file up-loads, but then again, if you don't have that event, then you may well have to dump your existing up-loader control and choose another. But then again, if you have such a event, use that to post-back.

Comment: I also use a up-loader (the ajaxtoolkit one). When a user uploads 1 (or maybe 3 files), I then update a list of files they just up-loaded. I could do this without a post-back, but then again, it don't matter since the files "already" are up-loaded, so a post-back right after the files are done up-loading don't matter. On the other hand, if you don't have a client side event that triggers after all files up-loaded, then you in big trouble already. but if you have such a event, then you can use that event to trigger a post back to update the file list - the user will not have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not familiar with the up-loader you are using. But, your posted code stub suggest this works "much" like the ajaxtoolkit one.

That means after "all" files been up-loaded, then no post-back occures.

As noted, you do probably want some up-loader that allows up-loading of files, and does NOT require a post-back.

However, after say 4 files are done up-loading, then it not all that bad to have a post-back trigger, and at that point in time trigger a post-back to refresh your grid of files, or listbox or whatever.

And note that one should "find" + "adopt" some up-loader for this purpose. A number "will" preview the picture file EVEN before the up-load starts. (however, I not really interested in that feature).

So, I use the ajax tool kit. It has 3 events (all do NOT post back).

Start up load stub.

One file done uploading stub. Here we save the file, add to our "file list". In my following example I use a grid view in place of a list box.

And I have some code that pulls out a first page for a image preview if this is a PDF. For images, then I just preview the image.

And a lot of the nice up-loaders also have a "hot spot" in which you can just drag + drop files.

And most are "chunked", and thus show a progress bar. And being chunked, then file size is un-limited, and you don't get a huge browser "spinner" while such large files up-load.

However, once ALL files are done, then I do fire a client side event, and I do so since I need/want to up-date my up-loaded file list. That is "why" I asked about what file up-loader you are using.

You COULD (and so could I with the aj toolkit file uploader) do a web call, get the new files, and fill out the listbox. But, I'm using a gridview, and I just do a Post-back to refresh it.

The results look like this:

[image]

So, while and after each file is up-loaded? No, I don't want a post-back.

However, once the list of files is up-loaded? Then yes, I do a post-back to update (refresh) the grid view.

So, it much depends on the file up-loader you are using.

As noted, your "code stub" suggests that your file up-loader has this ability (to trigger a client side javascript event when done).

So, what I did was drop a button on to the page, hide it (with style = display none).

And the aj fileuploader has a "all done" client side event.

this was my markup:

(not really imporant, but as a fyi:).

```
<div id="uploadfiles" runat="server" style="width: 550px; float: left">
    <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
        OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete"
        OnClientUploadCompleteAll="AllDone" />
</div>

<div id="myfiles" runat="server" style="float: left; width: 40%; margin-left: 30px">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridFiles" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover"
        OnRowDataBound="GridFiles_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpLoadTime" HeaderText="UpLoaded" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Pages" HeaderText="Pages" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="120px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <button id="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" class="btn myshadow"
                        onserverclick="cmdDownLoad_Click">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>
                    </button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn myshadow"
                        onclick="if (!delok(this)) {return false};"
                        onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    </button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
</div>
```

And I have this javascript code to refresh the grid view.

```
    <asp:Button ID="cmdLoadGrid" runat="server" Text="Button"
        style="display:none" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="cmdLoadGrid_Click"
        />

    <script>

        function AllDone() {
            $('#cmdLoadGrid').click()

        }
```

So, I in fact "click" the button after everything is done, since the aj fileupload does not do a post-back, and I in fact wanted one!

And my file save after up-load looks rather simular to what you have:

this:

```
Protected Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(sender As Object,
                                             e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)

    Dim sPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/")
    Dim sFilePath As String = sPath & e.FileName

    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(sFilePath)

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "INSERT INTO MyUploadFiles (FileName, UpLoadTime, Size, SavePath, Pages, Preview)
        Values (@FileName, @UpLoadTime, @Size, @SavePath, @Pages, @Preview)"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = e.FileName
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@UpLoadTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Now
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.FileSize
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@SavePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sPath

    Dim iBytes() As Byte
    Dim PageCount As Integer = 0
    Select Case Path.GetExtension(e.FileName)
        Case ".pdf"
            iBytes = GetPdfThumb2(sFilePath, PageCount)
        Case ".zip"
            iBytes = GimageF(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Pictures/zip.png"))
        Case ".bmp", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"
            iBytes = GimageF(sFilePath)
        Case Else
            ' use generatic picture
            iBytes = GimageF(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Pictures/generic.png"))

    End Select

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Pages", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PageCount
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Preview", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = iBytes

    MyrstPN(cmdSQL)


End Sub
```